# Django best practices for creating private user groups

Tags: python, django, server, django-rest-framework, backend

I'm creating a group app and I want it to be invitation only, but I'm wondering if there's a better way to do this. This setup works fine, but if anyone sees any issues I might run into please let me know. I've included the models and the views related to invitations, this should give you a good idea of my thought process here.

models.py

```
Account = get_user_model()


class FriendGroup(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(
        Account, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name="group_owner", null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    administrators = models.ManyToManyField(
        Account, related_name="group_admin")
    members = models.ManyToManyField(Account, related_name="group_member")
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/groups/', blank=True)
    image_lg = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/groups/', blank=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class GroupInvite(models.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey(
        FriendGroup, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="invite")
    sender = models.ForeignKey(
        Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="sent_by")
    invitee = models.ForeignKey(
        Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="invitee")

    def __str__(self):
        return "Join " + self.group.name
```

views.py

```
class SendGroupInvitesView(APIView):

    def post(self, request, pk, format=None):
        group = FriendGroup.objects.filter(id=pk)
        invitees = request.data.get('invitees')
        if group.exists():
            if request.user in group[0].members.all():
                if invitees:
                    for invitee in invitees:
                        account = Account.objects.filter(id=invitee)
                        if account.exists():
                            invite = GroupInvite.objects.create(
                                group=group[0], sender=request.user, invitee=account[0])
                            invite.save()
                    return Response({'success': 'Invites sent.'}, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
                return Response({'error': 'You must invite at least one friend.'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        return Response({'error': 'Group does not exist.'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)


class AcceptGroupInviteView(APIView):

    def post(self, request, pk, format=None):
        invite = GroupInvite.objects.filter(id=pk, invitee=request.user)
        if invite.exists():
            invite = invite[0]
            group = invite.group
            group.members.add(request.user)
            group.save()
            invite.delete()
            return Response({'success': 'Joined group.'}, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response({'error': 'Invite does not exist.'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)


class DeleteGroupInviteView(APIView):

    def post(self, request, pk, format=None):
        invite = GroupInvite.objects.filter(id=pk)
        if invite.exists():
            if invite[0].invitee == request.user or request.user in invite[0].group.members.all():
                invite = invite[0]
                invite.delete()
                return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
            return Response({'error': 'You are not authorized to delete this invite.'}, status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)
        return Response({'error': 'Invite does not exist.'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

I'm aware my code might seem a little bit sloppy, might make a Manager to clean things up a bit.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know all of you requirements in this task. But, in my humble opinion, you shouldn't use two m2m fields for this. M2M relations works not fast, so it would be better to decrease its count. Take a look at the intermediary models. It makes possible to take admin rights to the members via an additional field.

```
class GroupMembers(models.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey(FriendGroup...)
    member = models.ForeignKey(Account...)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)


class FriendGroup(models.Model):
    ...
    members = models.ManyToManyField(Account, through=GroupMembers)
    ...
```

See the docs at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships

Comment: I like this approach it makes a lot more sense, thanks